# car tire wear not pointed out

Tags: tires, wear

should a dealer allow you to leave lot with steel belt showing on tire?  This was after windshield replacement.  A multi-point safety inspection was recorded showing tire wear issue.  The only notation on paperwork noted 4/32 tread on tire with 1/3 of the tire showing bare steelbelt.  Is my outrage merited and what should expect from dealer?  Within 12 hours of leaving lot there was a flat on another tire with adequate tread - this time a split from rim to sidewall.

Comment: Did you check your tires **before** driving to the dealer?

Comment: In almost all places the OPERATOR of the vehicle is required to ensure that it's safe to drive before doing so.  If the dealer noted that the tires were worn it is your responsibility to do something about it.  What were they to do, block you from leaving or replace the tires without your approval?

Comment: Really you should have been checking the tyres regularly so that it never got into this condition.

Comment: A dealer? In UK it is a criminal offence to sell an unroadworthy vehicle, unless it is documented as sold for scrap.

Answer (score 1):

If this was your car and they let you go with what's on the paperwork, then it's on you. If the car was not yours before you entered the lot and there was no "we owe" slip involved, then it's on you. **Basically ... it's on you**.

Note: A "[we owe](https://mbrmarketing.com/dealer-supplies/sales-forms/we-owe-forms)" slip is where the dealership promised to do some sort of work for the car, in writing, in order for you to agree to purchase the vehicle. Fairly common in the States. I'm not sure about the rest of the world.